# How should I model this data in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, codable

I am trying to model the following data so it can be stored in a `CoreData`.

As it uses custom classes I am unsure how to model it correctly.

Each `Account` has an `id` and a `profile`

```swift
struct Account {
  let id: String
  let profile: UserProfile
}
```

Each profile has it's own `id`, a `name` and also an array of `Post`

```swift
struct UserProfile {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  let posts: [Post]
}
```

A post consists of `id`, an `authorId` that matches the id on profile and also a `title`

```swift
struct Post {
  let id: String
  let authorId: String // this maps to the UserProfile id field
  let title: String
}
```

An account can have 1 profile and vice versa. A profile however can have N number of `Posts`.

I assumed I would need 3 entities, Account, UserProfile and Post.

Account and UserProfile would have a one to one relationship.

I am unsure how to model UserProfile and Post.

Should a UserProfile have a one to many relationship with Post?

Is it possible for a Post to have one to one relationship with UserProfile and UserProfile have a one to many relationship with Post?

Also, I am assuming as CoreData does not support `Codable` the `profile` properties should not exist as a `Attribute` on `Account` and instead as a value in the  `Relationships` field instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
class Account : NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: String
  @NSManaged var profile: UserProfile?
}

class UserProfile : NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: String
  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var account: Account?
  @NSManaged var posts: Set<Post>
}

class Post : NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: String
  @NSManaged var author: UserProfile?
  @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

- `profile` in `Account` is a to-one relationship to `UserProfile`
- `account` in `UserProfile`is a to-one **reverse** relationship to `Account`
- `posts` in `UserProfile` is a to-many relationship to `Post`
- `author` in `Post` is a to-one **reverse** relationship to `UserProfile`

Reverse relationships are more efficient than maintain an attribute like `authorId` in `Post`

It is possible to adopt Codable in the Core Data classes (including the relationships) but the implementation is a bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you Vadian, as you mention Codable is a bit tricky, is it best to separate out each codable model to it's own entity and only work with the base types within those models such as `String`, `Int` and so on? Rather than encode as `Data` and just store the values?

Comment: It depends on your needs, there are several ways.

Comment: Can I ask why the optional references also please? For example in code, an Account cannot exist without a Profile and vice versa. Just for my own understanding now :)

Comment: The optionals are indeed not necessary. I had an issue in my implementation of `Codable` in Core Data relationships hence I declared the to-one relationships optional.

Comment: ah I see, amazing. Thank you for your help.